# Saving one row twice in one transaction doesn't give updated value (throws old value from database)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Assuming my balance for `productId: 1` is 0 initially
I selected twice from front end `i-e qty:2` and then `qty: 2` (balance of ProductId: 1 should be 4), but in my product table it saves qty to 2 instead of 4. Any help will be appreciated

note:
What I found out while debugging is, when it adds `ProductId:1` for second time in same transaction, it gets product balance as 0 instead of 2)

```
let productsToAdd= [{ qty: 2, ProducId: 1}, {qty: 2, ProducId: 1}, {qty: 2, ProducId: 1}] 
let t = sequelize.transaction 
Promise.all(productsToAdd.map(row => {
  let product = sequelize.product.findOne({ where: { id: row.ProductId }})
  product.balance += row.qty
  product.save({ transaction: t })
}))
```